# What happened to the reputation of this user?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

I found something strange in the reputation overview of [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/280934/?tab=reputation&sort=time).

It looks like he gained some up-votes, which didn't count, and after that he received more up-votes that did count. How is that possible? I've checked I sorted on time, so the votes should be ordered right. Also the answers aren't community wikis.

> [image: sorted on time]

Even [sorting on *post*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/280934/?tab=reputation&sort=post) shows he received reputation on 19:53, while another vote on 19:51 didn't count.

> [image: sorted on post]

What happened here? Did I miss something obvious? Or is it a bug in the layout maybe?

Comment: The 200 seems significant. Maybe after crossing the rep cap, he lost reputation, then gained some new?

Comment: But that lost rep should be in the overview, right? And it would correct the votes I think, so the earlier should count.

Comment: Also looks like serial upvoting. 7 upvotes in 1 minute...?

Comment: Then there should be a reversal notice.

Comment: @PatrickHofman there is, one day later. It shows only -10 because only one upvote that gave reputation was removed, but all those 7 upvotes are gone. For example see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/261398/timeline) - no upvotes in that date i.e. the vote simply vaporized as if it never existed.

Comment: @S.L.Barth see my above comment, you're right - can you post an answer please?

Comment: That seems likely yes @ShadowWizard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like serial voting was involved. 7 upvotes in 1 minute, all on different posts, is always suspicious.

As @Shadow Wizard observed, there is a reputation reversal notice later on. So the reputation was removed by the script against voting fraud.

Comment: That seems to be the case indeed. So to what post does the -10 apply? Having a hard time getting the time line straight.

Comment: Can't really know that, same applies for "user removed" - those don't give details about what posts exactly are affected

Comment: Okay, I was just wondering why it said -10 instead of -0 since he would have gained enough up-votes. The reversal doesn't seem to hurt him *on that specific day*.